# Neo4j Returning Nodes Instead of Relations

Tags: neo4j, cypher

In this Neo4j query, I want to return only relation and that only specific relation called "Permission". So how can I filter it and get the expected answer?

```
MATCH (end:Directory) WHERE end.name = "dir1.5" 
WITH shortestPath((start)-[*]->(end)) AS p
RETURN p
ORDER BY length(p)
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you have a `path`, you can filter on specific types of relationships doing this

```
WITH [r IN relationships(path) WHERE r.type = 'Permission'] AS rs
UNWIND rs AS r
RETURN r
```

If you want to visualize the r in the Neo4j broser, you may need to add the start and endnodes, so it becomes

```
RETURN startNode(r),r,endNode(r)
```